# Are Explicit Tags in mkdocs config supported in readthedocs?

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

I've been working on writing some mkdocs documentation which includes [mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) diagrams that I'd like to keep in the markdown files instead of turning into images and embedding them

I came across this great solution here: https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/693#issuecomment-411885426

Which uses the super-fences feature of the pymdown-extensions plugin to create a custom code block which renders the mermaid diagrams inside the code block.

It works in mkdocs running locally, but when I submit the configuration file to readthedocs it fails the yaml validation

```
Your mkdocs.yml could not be loaded, possibly due to a syntax error (line 18, column 19)
```

Line 18 in the mkdocs.yml config file is the section which calls the superfences python class

```
          format: !!python/name:pymdownx.superfences.fence_div_format
```

Looking in the yaml specification https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html Shows that `!!` is for an explicit tag and it seems to have been part of the spec for quite some time ( back to version 1). I've tried making the value a string but this then causes issue with python reading it as a string

Does anyone know if readthedocs supports this or have you been able to get this working some other way?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess that readthedocs considers `!!` tags to be a security vulnerability and explicitly disabled them in their YAML parser. Normally, MkDocs runs on your local machine where you have control over what code gets run. Any mistakes or errors only affect you. However, in readthedocs case, your code would be running on their system. If your code breaks their system, that could affect all their users, not just you, so they are never going to let that happen.

Answer (score 0):

ReadTheDocs is parsing the `mkdocs.yaml` file using `pyyaml` and it seems that it does not recognize `!!`.

For example:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> document = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c: 3
    d: !!4
"""
>>> print(yaml.dump(yaml.load(document)))
<stdin>:1: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 51, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 60, in construct_document
    for dummy in generator:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 413, in construct_yaml_map
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 218, in construct_mapping
    return super().construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 143, in construct_mapping
    value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 100, in construct_object
    data = constructor(self, node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 427, in construct_undefined
    raise ConstructorError(None, None,
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:4'
  in "<unicode string>", line 5, column 8:
        d: !!4
           ^
>>>
```

See: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/6889